# How did Malta catch up?

Tags: macroeconomics

How did Malta catch up with the likes of the United Kingdom and France (PPP constant 2017 international $) ? [image]

Comment: This is quite a broad question that would take too much time to answer. Short story is that it simply grew faster than those other countries but I don’t think that this is very satisfying. A detailed answer could talk about various policies they pursued but no country’s success is result of jut one or few policies so it would be too long for an SE format

Answer (score 1):

European airline deregulation in 1997 helped with tourism, Malta privatized some government assets, joined the EU in 2004, joined the Euro in 2008, history with the U.K. and use of English as a second language facilitated growth in services that than be provided internationally, such as insurance and asset management and anything on the internet,  lower taxes, and a starting point of lower living costs attracted business investment.

Some details from a 2007 article...

https://www.economist.com/business/2007/10/04/virtual-bridges

Comment: Do you maybe have some statistics on the individual growth rate of sectors, e.g. Maltese financial services vs. French/British financial services? Same for tourism? The share of these sectors of the countries' total economy in 1980 vs 2020 would also do.